# Documentation how to

Tags: ruby

How do I best navigate the core docs? What are others doing when curious about what methods are available on standard classes?

This other SO question is the same, but the accepted answer isn't cutting it for me.

I was trying

```
f = File.open("some-file.txt","w+")
```

and then wanted to check what methods I have available on f after this. I tried the following:

```
ri File.open -> Nothing known about File.open
```

The [core docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/) tells that File at least [doesn't define "open"](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html). But the page doesn't mention which modules File mixes in, or inherits from. So I wrote a script:

```
p File.open("foo.txt", "w+").methods
```

But this seems quite inefficient (not to mention a raw list of methods isn't the best documentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [pickaxe](http://whytheluckystiff.net/ruby/pickaxe/). It wasn't the be all and end all, but it was pretty decent.

Now I guess it would have to be http://ruby-doc.org

Comment: I think I'm gonna have to go with this. Only document so far which lists inheritance, and mixins. Like you say, not awesome, but a good jumping off point I suppose

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `ri File` and it will give you full info on the File class (including the methods it implements and its superclass) or `ri open` (which will tell you all the places `open` is implemented if there are several).

Comment: My ri File doesn't show anything beyond http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html - It doesn't mention any superclass, or modules it includes.

Comment: That's an installation issue then.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the documentation on your system from a browser.  [This](http://www.paulgillard.me.uk/2008/10/9/offline-ruby-documentation/) details how to set it  up.

Answer (score 0):

I found Fxri is useful when you want to browse what method is avaiable for certain object. 
It is default in Ruby windows install package.

https://rubygems.org/gems/fxri/

Comment: This is alot easier (and fast) to search in, but I'm not seeing anything in there, that couldn't be gleaned from the standard docs. That is, no info on where File inherits the open method from, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I usually just go to google and enter "Ruby [method name]" and what I want is almost always in the top three results.  If it's not, I fall back to rubybrain.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://apidock.com/ruby for Ruby documentation and the site also features Rails and RSpec documentation.